# Proving the existence of a compact subset using Picards Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $K$ be a compact set in $\mathbb{C} \setminus [0,1]$, let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$ be a connected open set, and let $f:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C} \setminus [0,1]$ be a holomorphic map. Also let $c \in \Omega$ and $E \subset \subset \Omega$. Prove there exist a compact set $L \subset  \mathbb{C} \setminus [0,1]$ depending only on $K, \Omega$, and $E$, such that if $f(c) \in K$, then $f(E) \subset L$.

Comment: What do you mean by C{0,1}?

Comment: My head hurts trying to read this question. Please format it and rephrase it so it's understandable.